# Get the value of array in multidimensional-array in array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I get the value of an array in a multidimensional array...in another array?

I want to get the value of `test` in ascending order in the following code.

I tried to use a `for` and `foreach` loops but have had problems when it comes to referencing an element of the multidimensional array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[][,][] test = { new string[,][]{{
                                               new string[]{"test1","test2","test3"},
                                               new string[]{"test4","test6","test6"}
                                           },
                                           {
                                               new string[]{"test7","test7","test9"},
                                               new string[]{"test10","test11","test12"}
                                           }},
                           new string[,][]{{
                                               new string[]{"test13","test14","test15"},
                                               new string[]{"test16","test17","test18"}
                                           },
                                           {
                                               new string[]{"test19","test20","test21"},
                                               new string[]{"test22","test23","test24"}
                                           }}
                         };
    for (int a = 0; a < test.Count(); a++ )
    {
        foreach(var am in test[a])
        {
            for (int ama = 0; ama < am.Count(); ama++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",test[a][0,0][ama].ToString()); //what should I put in [0,0]?
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", am[ama].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `foreach` you could also use `for` as follows:

```
  for ( int a = 0; a < test.Count(); a++ )
  {
    string[,][] ta = test[a];
    for( int i1 = 0; i1 < ta.GetLength( 0 ); i1++ )
    {
      for( int i2 = 0; i2 < ta.GetLength( 1 ); i2++ )
      {
        string[] am = ta[i1, i2];
        for ( int ama = 0; ama < am.Count(); ama++ )
        {
          Console.WriteLine( "{0}", test[ a ][ i1, i2 ][ ama ].ToString() );
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Leonel,

Here is your code working:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[][,][] test = { new string[,][]{{
                                                   new string[]{"test1","test2","test3"},
                                                   new string[]{"test4","test5","test6"}
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   new string[]{"test7","test8","test9"},
                                                   new string[]{"test10","test11","test12"}
                                               }},
                               new string[,][]{{
                                                   new string[]{"test13","test14","test15"},
                                                   new string[]{"test16","test17","test18"}
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   new string[]{"test19","test20","test21"},
                                                   new string[]{"test22","test23","test24"}
                                               }}
                             };
        for (int a = 0; a < test.Count(); a++)
        {
            foreach(string[] am in test[a])
            {
                for (int ama = 0; ama < am.Count(); ama++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", am[ama].ToString()); //Reference to the inside loop
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

There is no need to reference the entire array in your print statement. You only need to reference the inside loop. Hope that helps.

Best Wishes,
Bill